# Get a list of attribute options from Magento

Tags: php, attributes, magento, multi-select

I've been grabbing attribute options from Magento like so:

```
<?php

if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
}

?>
```

It's been working fine until I tried to get the options for the built in 'color' attribute -- I got the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php on line 374
```

It would appear that the `getSource()` call fails and causes this error. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can get color options out?

Thanks!

Comment: have you been able to debug it live with xdebug and your IDE?  You might be able to drill into the $attribute->getSource() call to see what's failing in there.  I don't know of any reason why `color` should be any different to other attributes.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It looks like that you initialize attribute by yourself, instead of using Magento attribute initialization process:

```
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute($entityType, $attributeCode)
```

Because since 1.4.x Magento has separate attribute models for catalog and customers model and definition of default source model for `catalog_product` now is moved from EAV attribute model (`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute`) to the catalog one (`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute`).

As a result, some catalog attributes won't work with the EAV attribute model. Particularly those that use `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table` but don't explicitly define it (color, manufacturer, etc.).

The following code snippet should work perfectly on your installation:

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color');

if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
}
```

By the way `Mage_Eav_Model_Config` model has a lot of helpful methods, that can be used in your development, so don't hesitate to look into this model.

Comment: Thanks. In add to the answer, when dealing with 'catalog_product' it uses Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table class and the parameters are: getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false).  Thank you one more time.

Answer (score 8):

The above code does not work if the resource_model is empty. The following snippet does the job:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');

/** @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */
$valuesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
->setStoreFilter(0, false);
```

Comment: Please consider that this solution doesn't take care about the attribute values sort order. $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) does

Answer (score 5):

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer','cateinterest');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

Comment: please add more details on your answer

Comment: This works for eav attributes that don't populate using the above methods

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  //Possible color value
  $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color'); //"color" is the attribute_code
  $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
  foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
    $id = $instance['value']; //id of the option
    $value = $instance['label']; //Label of the option
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer and add some explanation why/how your code solves the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for an incomplete answer, but take a look at the database, specifically in the `backend_model` column. I seem to remember having this same problem until I set this field to match some of the system fields in this respect.